# why or where is BOOST_ASIO_HAS_IOCP defined?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Recently I was starting a new project using boost asio but I permanently get an error:
`'SO_UPDATE_CONNECT_CONTEXT' was not declared in this scope`. I know what this error means but I can't find the definition of `BOOST_ASIO_HAS_IOCP` which is needed to get in the scope of the function `complete_iocp_connect` in the file `socket_ops.ipp`.

I'm using g++ 4.8.1 but I also get an error with version 4.6.2. OS is Windows 7 64 bit. I use the repository version (git) with tag `boost-1.55.0`.

I startet some projects in the past where such an error doesn't occur, so why or where is `BOOST_ASIO_HAS_IOCP` defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BOOST_ASIO_HAS_IOCP` is likely just detected when Boost is configured on Windows.

If it's not, boost/asio/detail/config.hpp defines it:

```
#if !defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_IOCP)
# if defined(BOOST_ASIO_WINDOWS) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
#  if defined(_WIN32_WINNT) && (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0400)
#   if !defined(UNDER_CE)
#    if !defined(BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP)
#     define BOOST_ASIO_HAS_IOCP 1
#    endif // !defined(BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP)
#   endif // !defined(UNDER_CE)
#  endif // defined(_WIN32_WINNT) && (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0400)
# endif // defined(BOOST_ASIO_WINDOWS) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
#endif // !defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_IOCP)
```

It appears that your boost was configured with a different value for _WIN32_WINNT than used during the build of your application.

Can you try defining it to 0x0501 or higher?

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 // _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP
```

(somewhat related ticket https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10016)

Comment: yes that whas helpful for this error, but actually after this I get a lot of new errors with same type: `BOOST_APPLICATION_TYPE_INDEX_SELECT has not been declared` for example. Is it possible that there are many missconfigured options on my working machine? I mean I use the untouched boost version from git and also tried it with the zip version (version 1.55.0) (except loading boost.application into it)

Comment: Mmm. Let me just get this straight, did you just reject my answer because it doesn't solve a different error that you hadn't told anyone about? In fact you haven't even mentioned that you are using external libraries (Boost Application) with this. This deserves a new question, with a link to the download location and a http://sscce.org